# How to filter out all rows that contain a symbol "

Tags: python, pyspark

I want to filter out all rows that contain the symbol " in the column "Col1".

```
Col1   Col2
11"    A
0!     Q
123456 A
252653 A
343535 A
```

Expected result:

```
Col1   Col2
123456 A
252653 A
343535 A
```

To do it, I decided to filter out all non-digital values:

```
def is_digit(value):
    if value:
        return value.isdigit()
    else:
        return False

is_digit_udf = udf(lambda value: is_digit(value), BooleanType())

df.filter(when(is_digit_udf(df["Col1"]))).show()
```

However this code fails with the error message:

> TypeError: when() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`when` function is the equivalent of `case when` in sql. 
Therefore, it cannot be used directly in a `filter`. You can try this :

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
df.filter(is_digit_udf(df["Col1"]))==lit(True)).show()
```

Answer (score -1):

Creating the provided input Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

Data = {'Col1': ['11"', '0!', '123456', '252653', '343535'], 'Col2': ['A', 'Q', 'A', 'A', 'A']}

df = pd.DataFrame(Data)
```

To remove the desired string content from a specific column I use this:

```
df.drop(df[df['Col1'].str.contains('"')].index, inplace=True)
```

Where '**Col1**' is the desired column and ' **"** ' is de desired content

Output:

```
Col1   Col2
0!     Q
123456 A
252653 A
343535 A
```

You want to filter non-digit or strings that contain **"**?

Comment: it's a spark dataframe issue ... not pandas !